# How to stop opening the browser when establishing connection to Snowflake using create engine in Python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm using the create_engine of SQL Alchemy to connect to the Snowflake database from Python.  I used "externalbrowser" as the authenticator parameter.  Every time I run this, a browser opens to authenticate.  How do I stop a browser opening every time I try to connect to Snowflake?

Answer (score 2):

With externalbrowser, the functionality is to have the browser opened for authentication and this is the intended operation mechanism. If that is not something you want to have then use Oauth mechanism, key-pair or if the authentication engine is Okta, use native okta authentication.

If the overall objective is to reduce the number of times pop-up shows up then you can set ALLOW_ID_TOKEN parameter which would cache the authentication information.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use.html#using-connection-caching-to-minimize-the-number-of-prompts-for-authentication-optional